# Bad Request 400 - Freeswitch CLI Oiriginate Connect two Clients

Tags: command-line-interface, freeswitch

Im Trying to use Freeswitch CLI to trigger a call between to SIP Clients:

```
 originate sofia/internal/5003%192.168.2.180 &bridge(sofia/internal/linphone%192.168.2.180)
```

It always calls the first client and the second call fails. Making Calls between the Clients works perfectly. Its all a internal setup only.

Any suggestions on what it could be?

siptrace:

```
    freeswitch@freeswitch-vm> originate sofia/internal/5003%192.168.2.180 &bridge(sofia/internal/linphone%192.168.2.180)
+OK d6f539ec-e763-4c0e-8864-fbc53eab8b93

2019-06-21 05:12:33.931678 [DEBUG] switch_ivr_originate.c:2136 Parsing global variables
2019-06-21 05:12:33.931678 [NOTICE] switch_channel.c:1104 New Channel sofia/internal/5003 [d6f539ec-e763-4c0e-8864-fbc53eab8b93]
2019-06-21 05:12:33.931678 [DEBUG] mod_sofia.c:4753 (sofia/internal/5003) State Change CS_NEW -> CS_INIT
2019-06-21 05:12:33.931678 [DEBUG] switch_core_state_machine.c:543 (sofia/internal/5003) Running State Change CS_INIT
2019-06-21 05:12:33.931678 [DEBUG] switch_core_state_machine.c:586 (sofia/internal/5003) State INIT
2019-06-21 05:12:33.931678 [DEBUG] mod_sofia.c:90 sofia/internal/5003 SOFIA INIT
2019-06-21 05:12:33.950925 [DEBUG] sofia_glue.c:1276 sofia/internal/5003 sending invite version: 1.6.10 -17-726448d 64bit
Local SDP:
v=0
o=FreeSWITCH 1561079777 1561079778 IN IP4 192.168.2.180
s=FreeSWITCH
c=IN IP4 192.168.2.180
t=0 0
m=audio 32176 RTP/AVP 102 9 0 8 104 101
a=rtpmap:102 opus/48000/2
a=fmtp:102 useinbandfec=1; maxaveragebitrate=30000; maxplaybackrate=48000; ptime=20; minptime=10; maxptime=40
a=rtpmap:9 G722/8000
a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000
a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000
a=rtpmap:104 telephone-event/48000
a=fmtp:104 0-16
a=rtpmap:101 telephone-event/8000
a=fmtp:101 0-16
a=ptime:20
a=sendrecv
m=video 19038 RTP/AVP 103
b=AS:1024
a=rtpmap:103 VP8/90000
a=rtcp-fb:103 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:103 ccm tmmbr
a=rtcp-fb:103 nack
a=rtcp-fb:103 nack pli

2019-06-21 05:12:33.950925 [DEBUG] switch_core_state_machine.c:40 sofia/internal/5003 Standard INIT
2019-06-21 05:12:33.950925 [DEBUG] switch_core_state_machine.c:48 (sofia/internal/5003) State Change CS_INIT -> CS_ROUTING
2019-06-21 05:12:33.950925 [DEBUG] switch_core_state_machine.c:586 (sofia/internal/5003) State INIT going to sleep
2019-06-21 05:12:33.950925 [DEBUG] switch_core_state_machine.c:543 (sofia/internal/5003) Running State Change CS_ROUTING
2019-06-21 05:12:33.950925 [DEBUG] switch_core_state_machine.c:602 (sofia/internal/5003) State ROUTING
2019-06-21 05:12:33.950925 [DEBUG] mod_sofia.c:143 sofia/internal/5003 SOFIA ROUTING
2019-06-21 05:12:33.950925 [DEBUG] switch_ivr_originate.c:67 (sofia/internal/5003) State Change CS_ROUTING -> CS_CONSUME_MEDIA
send 1556 bytes to udp/[192.168.2.181]:5060 at 05:12:33.952162:
   ------------------------------------------------------------------------
   INVITE sip:5003@192.168.2.181:5060;ob SIP/2.0
   Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 192.168.2.180;rport;branch=z9hG4bKjD1mZ9cZ8gDtB
   Max-Forwards: 70
   From: "" <sip:0000000000@192.168.2.180>;tag=tc5B4j279yjSD
   To: <sip:5003@192.168.2.181:5060;ob>
   Call-ID: ed928166-0eaf-1238-7aa7-080027ca0286
   CSeq: 6002184 INVITE
   Contact: <sip:mod_sofia@192.168.2.180:5060>
   User-Agent: FreeSWITCH-mod_sofia/1.6.10-17-726448d~64bit
   Allow: INVITE, ACK, BYE, CANCEL, OPTIONS, MESSAGE, INFO, UPDATE, REGISTER, REFER, NOTIFY, PUBLISH, SUBSCRIBE
   Supported: timer, path, replaces
   Allow-Events: talk, hold, conference, presence, as-feature-event, dialog, line-seize, call-info, sla, include-session-description, presence.winfo, message-summary, refer
   Content-Type: application/sdp
   Content-Disposition: session
   Content-Length: 625
   X-FS-Support: update_display,send_info
   Remote-Party-ID: <sip:0000000000@192.168.2.180>;party=calling;screen=yes;privacy=off

   v=0
   o=FreeSWITCH 1561079777 1561079778 IN IP4 192.168.2.180
   s=FreeSWITCH
   c=IN IP4 192.168.2.180
   t=0 0
   m=audio 32176 RTP/AVP 102 9 0 8 104 101
   a=rtpmap:102 opus/48000/2
   a=fmtp:102 useinbandfec=1; maxaveragebitrate=30000; maxplaybackrate=48000; ptime=20; minptime=10; maxptime=40
   a=rtpmap:9 G722/8000
   a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000
   a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000
   a=rtpmap:104 telephone-event/48000
   a=fmtp:104 0-16
   a=rtpmap:101 telephone-event/8000
   a=fmtp:101 0-16
   a=ptime:20
   m=video 19038 RTP/AVP 103
   b=AS:1024
   a=rtpmap:103 VP8/90000
   a=rtcp-fb:103 ccm fir
   a=rtcp-fb:103 ccm tmmbr
   a=rtcp-fb:103 nack
   a=rtcp-fb:103 nack pli
   ------------------------------------------------------------------------
2019-06-21 05:12:33.950925 [DEBUG] switch_core_state_machine.c:602 (sofia/internal/5003) State ROUTING going to sleep
2019-06-21 05:12:33.950925 [DEBUG] switch_core_state_machine.c:543 (sofia/internal/5003) Running State Change CS_CONSUME_MEDIA
2019-06-21 05:12:33.950925 [DEBUG] sofia.c:6962 Channel sofia/internal/5003 entering state [calling][0]
2019-06-21 05:12:33.950925 [DEBUG] switch_core_state_machine.c:621 (sofia/internal/5003) State CONSUME_MEDIA
2019-06-21 05:12:33.950925 [DEBUG] switch_core_state_machine.c:621 (sofia/internal/5003) State CONSUME_MEDIA going to sleep
recv 298 bytes from udp/[192.168.2.181]:5060 at 05:12:33.966566:
   ------------------------------------------------------------------------
   SIP/2.0 100 Trying
   Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 192.168.2.180;rport=5060;received=192.168.2.180;branch=z9hG4bKjD1mZ9cZ8gDtB
   Call-ID: ed928166-0eaf-1238-7aa7-080027ca0286
   From: <sip:0000000000@192.168.2.180>;tag=tc5B4j279yjSD
   To: <sip:5003@192.168.2.181;ob>
   CSeq: 6002184 INVITE
   Content-Length:  0

   ------------------------------------------------------------------------
recv 482 bytes from udp/[192.168.2.181]:5060 at 05:12:34.002969:
   ------------------------------------------------------------------------
   SIP/2.0 180 Ringing
   Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 192.168.2.180;rport=5060;received=192.168.2.180;branch=z9hG4bKjD1mZ9cZ8gDtB
   Call-ID: ed928166-0eaf-1238-7aa7-080027ca0286
   From: <sip:0000000000@192.168.2.180>;tag=tc5B4j279yjSD
   To: <sip:5003@192.168.2.181;ob>;tag=e26f5b27-ba66-4dec-ba73-ec2fe95f3fd6
   CSeq: 6002184 INVITE
   Contact: <sip:5003@192.168.2.181:5060;ob>
   Allow: PRACK, INVITE, ACK, BYE, CANCEL, UPDATE, INFO, SUBSCRIBE, NOTIFY, REFER, MESSAGE, OPTIONS
   Content-Length:  0

   ------------------------------------------------------------------------
2019-06-21 05:12:33.973497 [DEBUG] sofia.c:6962 Channel sofia/internal/5003 entering state [proceeding][180]
2019-06-21 05:12:33.973497 [NOTICE] sofia.c:7070 Ring-Ready sofia/internal/5003!
2019-06-21 05:12:33.973497 [DEBUG] switch_channel.c:3343 (sofia/internal/5003) Callstate Change DOWN -> RINGING
recv 897 bytes from udp/[192.168.2.181]:5060 at 05:12:34.174942:
   ------------------------------------------------------------------------
   SIP/2.0 200 OK
   Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 192.168.2.180;rport=5060;received=192.168.2.180;branch=z9hG4bKjD1mZ9cZ8gDtB
   Call-ID: ed928166-0eaf-1238-7aa7-080027ca0286
   From: <sip:0000000000@192.168.2.180>;tag=tc5B4j279yjSD
   To: <sip:5003@192.168.2.181;ob>;tag=e26f5b27-ba66-4dec-ba73-ec2fe95f3fd6
   CSeq: 6002184 INVITE
   Allow: PRACK, INVITE, ACK, BYE, CANCEL, UPDATE, INFO, SUBSCRIBE, NOTIFY, REFER, MESSAGE, OPTIONS
   Contact: <sip:5003@192.168.2.181:5060;ob>
   Supported: replaces, 100rel, timer, norefersub
   Content-Type: application/sdp
   Content-Length:   338

   v=0
   o=- 3770100759 3770100760 IN IP4 192.168.2.181
   s=pjmedia
   b=AS:1498
   t=0 0
   a=X-nat:0
   m=audio 8000 RTP/AVP 9 101
   c=IN IP4 192.168.2.181
   b=TIAS:1411200
   a=rtcp:8001 IN IP4 192.168.2.181
   a=sendrecv
   a=rtpmap:9 G722/8000
   a=rtpmap:101 telephone-event/8000
   a=fmtp:101 0-16
   m=video 0 RTP/AVP 103
   c=IN IP4 127.0.0.1
   b=AS:1024
   ------------------------------------------------------------------------
2019-06-21 05:12:34.171043 [DEBUG] sofia.c:6962 Channel sofia/internal/5003 entering state [completing][200]
2019-06-21 05:12:34.171043 [DEBUG] sofia.c:6972 Remote SDP:
v=0
o=- 3770100759 3770100760 IN IP4 192.168.2.181
s=pjmedia
b=AS:1498
t=0 0
a=X-nat:0
m=audio 8000 RTP/AVP 9 101
c=IN IP4 192.168.2.181
b=TIAS:1411200
a=rtpmap:9 G722/8000
a=rtpmap:101 telephone-event/8000
a=fmtp:101 0-16
a=rtcp:8001 IN IP4 192.168.2.181
m=video 0 RTP/AVP 103
c=IN IP4 127.0.0.1
b=AS:1024

send 403 bytes to udp/[192.168.2.181]:5060 at 05:12:34.177702:
   ------------------------------------------------------------------------
   ACK sip:5003@192.168.2.181:5060;ob SIP/2.0
   Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 192.168.2.180;rport;branch=z9hG4bKKptD14X25S3cQ
   Max-Forwards: 70
   From: "" <sip:0000000000@192.168.2.180>;tag=tc5B4j279yjSD
   To: <sip:5003@192.168.2.181:5060;ob>;tag=e26f5b27-ba66-4dec-ba73-ec2fe95f3fd6
   Call-ID: ed928166-0eaf-1238-7aa7-080027ca0286
   CSeq: 6002184 ACK
   Contact: <sip:mod_sofia@192.168.2.180:5060>
   Content-Length: 0

   ------------------------------------------------------------------------
2019-06-21 05:12:34.171043 [DEBUG] sofia.c:6962 Channel sofia/internal/5003 entering state [ready][200]
2019-06-21 05:12:34.171043 [DEBUG] switch_core_media.c:4276 Audio Codec Compare [G722:9:8000:20:64000:1]/[opus:116:48000:20:0:1]
2019-06-21 05:12:34.171043 [DEBUG] switch_core_media.c:4276 Audio Codec Compare [G722:9:8000:20:64000:1]/[G722:9:8000:20:64000:1]
2019-06-21 05:12:34.171043 [DEBUG] switch_core_media.c:4331 Audio Codec Compare [G722:9:8000:20:64000:1] ++++ is saved as a match
2019-06-21 05:12:34.171043 [DEBUG] switch_core_media.c:4276 Audio Codec Compare [G722:9:8000:20:64000:1]/[PCMU:0:8000:20:64000:1]
2019-06-21 05:12:34.171043 [DEBUG] switch_core_media.c:4276 Audio Codec Compare [G722:9:8000:20:64000:1]/[PCMA:8:8000:20:64000:1]
2019-06-21 05:12:34.171043 [DEBUG] switch_core_media.c:4192 Set telephone-event payload to 101@8000
2019-06-21 05:12:34.171043 [DEBUG] switch_core_media.c:3017 Set Codec sofia/internal/5003 G722/8000 20 ms 160 samples 64000 bits 1 channels
2019-06-21 05:12:34.171043 [DEBUG] switch_core_codec.c:111 sofia/internal/5003 Original read codec set to G722:9
2019-06-21 05:12:34.171043 [DEBUG] switch_core_media.c:4537 Set telephone-event payload to 101@8000
2019-06-21 05:12:34.171043 [DEBUG] switch_core_media.c:4596 sofia/internal/5003 Set 2833 dtmf send payload to 101 recv payload to 101
2019-06-21 05:12:34.171043 [DEBUG] switch_core_media.c:6434 AUDIO RTP [sofia/internal/5003] 192.168.2.180 port 32176 -> 192.168.2.181 port 8000 codec: 9 ms: 20
2019-06-21 05:12:34.171043 [DEBUG] switch_rtp.c:3824 Starting timer [soft] 160 bytes per 20ms
2019-06-21 05:12:34.171043 [DEBUG] switch_core_media.c:6652 Activating RTCP PORT 8001
2019-06-21 05:12:34.171043 [DEBUG] switch_rtp.c:4210 RTCP send rate is: 5000 and packet rate is: 20000 Remote Port: 8001
2019-06-21 05:12:34.171043 [DEBUG] switch_core_media.c:6733 sofia/internal/5003 Set 2833 dtmf send payload to 101
2019-06-21 05:12:34.171043 [DEBUG] switch_core_media.c:6740 sofia/internal/5003 Set 2833 dtmf receive payload to 101
2019-06-21 05:12:34.171043 [DEBUG] switch_core_media.c:6763 sofia/internal/5003 Set rtp dtmf delay to 40
2019-06-21 05:12:34.171043 [NOTICE] sofia.c:7993 Channel [sofia/internal/5003] has been answered
2019-06-21 05:12:34.171043 [DEBUG] switch_ivr_originate.c:3616 Originate Resulted in Success: [sofia/internal/5003]
2019-06-21 05:12:34.171043 [DEBUG] switch_channel.c:3770 (sofia/internal/5003) Callstate Change RINGING -> ACTIVE
2019-06-21 05:12:34.171043 [INFO] switch_channel.c:3127 sofia/internal/5003 Flipping CID from "" <0000000000> to "Outbound Call" <5003%192.168.2.180>
2019-06-21 05:12:34.171043 [DEBUG] mod_commands.c:4785 (sofia/internal/5003) State Change CS_CONSUME_MEDIA -> CS_EXECUTE
2019-06-21 05:12:34.171043 [DEBUG] switch_core_state_machine.c:543 (sofia/internal/5003) Running State Change CS_EXECUTE
2019-06-21 05:12:34.171043 [DEBUG] switch_core_state_machine.c:609 (sofia/internal/5003) State EXECUTE
2019-06-21 05:12:34.171043 [DEBUG] mod_sofia.c:198 sofia/internal/5003 SOFIA EXECUTE
2019-06-21 05:12:34.171043 [DEBUG] switch_core_state_machine.c:328 sofia/internal/5003 Standard EXECUTE
EXECUTE sofia/internal/5003 bridge(sofia/internal/linphone%192.168.2.180)
2019-06-21 05:12:34.171043 [DEBUG] switch_channel.c:1823 (sofia/internal/5003) Callstate Change ACTIVE -> RING_WAIT
2019-06-21 05:12:34.171043 [DEBUG] switch_ivr_originate.c:2136 Parsing global variables
2019-06-21 05:12:34.171043 [NOTICE] switch_channel.c:1104 New Channel sofia/internal/linphone [a8adcc82-8819-4e0d-a332-b270b61da925]
2019-06-21 05:12:34.171043 [DEBUG] mod_sofia.c:4753 (sofia/internal/linphone) State Change CS_NEW -> CS_INIT
2019-06-21 05:12:34.171043 [DEBUG] switch_core_state_machine.c:543 (sofia/internal/linphone) Running State Change CS_INIT
2019-06-21 05:12:34.171043 [DEBUG] switch_core_state_machine.c:586 (sofia/internal/linphone) State INIT
2019-06-21 05:12:34.171043 [DEBUG] mod_sofia.c:90 sofia/internal/linphone SOFIA INIT
2019-06-21 05:12:34.171043 [DEBUG] sofia_glue.c:1276 sofia/internal/linphone sending invite version: 1.6.10 -17-726448d 64bit
Local SDP:
v=0
o=FreeSWITCH 1561093772 1561093773 IN IP4 192.168.2.180
s=FreeSWITCH
c=IN IP4 192.168.2.180
t=0 0
m=audio 18182 RTP/AVP 9 101
a=rtpmap:9 G722/8000
a=rtpmap:101 telephone-event/8000
a=fmtp:101 0-16
a=ptime:20
a=sendrecv

2019-06-21 05:12:34.171043 [DEBUG] switch_core_state_machine.c:40 sofia/internal/linphone Standard INIT
2019-06-21 05:12:34.171043 [DEBUG] switch_core_state_machine.c:48 (sofia/internal/linphone) State Change CS_INIT -> CS_ROUTING
2019-06-21 05:12:34.171043 [DEBUG] switch_core_state_machine.c:586 (sofia/internal/linphone) State INIT going to sleep
2019-06-21 05:12:34.171043 [DEBUG] switch_core_state_machine.c:543 (sofia/internal/linphone) Running State Change CS_ROUTING
send 1218 bytes to udp/[192.168.28.31]:5060 at 05:12:34.189358:
   ------------------------------------------------------------------------
   INVITE sip:linphone@192.168.28.31;transport=udp SIP/2.0
   Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 192.168.2.180;rport;branch=z9hG4bKmZK62Ze622SZj
   Max-Forwards: 70
   From: "Outbound Call" <sip:50032.168.2.180@192.168.2.180>;tag=UNy45DKB778BS
   To: <sip:linphone@192.168.28.31;transport=udp>
   Call-ID: edb6b4b1-0eaf-1238-7aa7-080027ca0286
   CSeq: 6002185 INVITE
   Contact: <sip:mod_sofia@192.168.2.180:5060>
   User-Agent: FreeSWITCH-mod_sofia/1.6.10-17-726448d~64bit
   Allow: INVITE, ACK, BYE, CANCEL, OPTIONS, MESSAGE, INFO, UPDATE, REGISTER, REFER, NOTIFY, PUBLISH, SUBSCRIBE
   Supported: timer, path, replaces
   Allow-Events: talk, hold, conference, presence, as-feature-event, dialog, line-seize, call-info, sla, include-session-description, presence.winfo, message-summary, refer
   Content-Type: application/sdp
   Content-Disposition: session
   Content-Length: 224
   X-FS-Support: update_display,send_info
   Remote-Party-ID: "Outbound Call" <sip:5003%192.168.2.180@192.168.2.180>;party=calling;screen=yes;privacy=off

   v=0
   o=FreeSWITCH 1561093772 1561093773 IN IP4 192.168.2.180
   s=FreeSWITCH
   c=IN IP4 192.168.2.180
   t=0 0
   m=audio 18182 RTP/AVP 9 101
   a=rtpmap:9 G722/8000
   a=rtpmap:101 telephone-event/8000
   a=fmtp:101 0-16
   a=ptime:20
   ------------------------------------------------------------------------
2019-06-21 05:12:34.171043 [DEBUG] switch_core_state_machine.c:602 (sofia/internal/linphone) State ROUTING
2019-06-21 05:12:34.171043 [DEBUG] mod_sofia.c:143 sofia/internal/linphone SOFIA ROUTING
2019-06-21 05:12:34.171043 [DEBUG] switch_ivr_originate.c:67 (sofia/internal/linphone) State Change CS_ROUTING -> CS_CONSUME_MEDIA
2019-06-21 05:12:34.171043 [DEBUG] switch_core_state_machine.c:602 (sofia/internal/linphone) State ROUTING going to sleep
2019-06-21 05:12:34.171043 [DEBUG] switch_core_state_machine.c:543 (sofia/internal/linphone) Running State Change CS_CONSUME_MEDIA
2019-06-21 05:12:34.171043 [DEBUG] sofia.c:6962 Channel sofia/internal/linphone entering state [calling][0]
2019-06-21 05:12:34.171043 [DEBUG] switch_core_state_machine.c:621 (sofia/internal/linphone) State CONSUME_MEDIA
2019-06-21 05:12:34.171043 [DEBUG] switch_core_state_machine.c:621 (sofia/internal/linphone) State CONSUME_MEDIA going to sleep
recv 221 bytes from udp/[192.168.28.31]:5060 at 05:12:34.203391:
   ------------------------------------------------------------------------
   SIP/2.0 400 Bad request
   Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 192.168.2.180;rport;branch=z9hG4bKmZK62Ze622SZj
   To: <sip:linphone@192.168.28.31;transport=udp>;tag=oUWqD
   Call-ID: edb6b4b1-0eaf-1238-7aa7-080027ca0286
   CSeq: 6002185 INVITE

   ------------------------------------------------------------------------
2019-06-21 05:12:34.231177 [DEBUG] switch_rtp.c:6721 Correct audio ip/port confirmed.
2019-06-21 05:12:34.251475 [DEBUG] switch_rtp.c:1847 rtcp_stats_init: audio ssrc[989071824] base_seq[9414]
send 1218 bytes to udp/[192.168.28.31]:5060 at 05:12:35.194482:
   ------------------------------------------------------------------------
   INVITE sip:linphone@192.168.28.31;transport=udp SIP/2.0
   Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 192.168.2.180;rport;branch=z9hG4bKmZK62Ze622SZj
   Max-Forwards: 70
   From: "Outbound Call" <sip:50032.168.2.180@192.168.2.180>;tag=UNy45DKB778BS
   To: <sip:linphone@192.168.28.31;transport=udp>
   Call-ID: edb6b4b1-0eaf-1238-7aa7-080027ca0286
   CSeq: 6002185 INVITE
   Contact: <sip:mod_sofia@192.168.2.180:5060>
   User-Agent: FreeSWITCH-mod_sofia/1.6.10-17-726448d~64bit
   Allow: INVITE, ACK, BYE, CANCEL, OPTIONS, MESSAGE, INFO, UPDATE, REGISTER, REFER, NOTIFY, PUBLISH, SUBSCRIBE
   Supported: timer, path, replaces
   Allow-Events: talk, hold, conference, presence, as-feature-event, dialog, line-seize, call-info, sla, include-session-description, presence.winfo, message-summary, refer
   Content-Type: application/sdp
   Content-Disposition: session
   Content-Length: 224
   X-FS-Support: update_display,send_info
   Remote-Party-ID: "Outbound Call" <sip:5003%192.168.2.180@192.168.2.180>;party=calling;screen=yes;privacy=off

   v=0
   o=FreeSWITCH 1561093772 1561093773 IN IP4 192.168.2.180
   s=FreeSWITCH
   c=IN IP4 192.168.2.180
   t=0 0
   m=audio 18182 RTP/AVP 9 101
   a=rtpmap:9 G722/8000
   a=rtpmap:101 telephone-event/8000
   a=fmtp:101 0-16
   a=ptime:20
   ------------------------------------------------------------------------
recv 221 bytes from udp/[192.168.28.31]:5060 at 05:12:35.201925:
   ------------------------------------------------------------------------
   SIP/2.0 400 Bad request
   Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 192.168.2.180;rport;branch=z9hG4bKmZK62Ze622SZj
   To: <sip:linphone@192.168.28.31;transport=udp>;tag=oUWqD
   Call-ID: edb6b4b1-0eaf-1238-7aa7-080027ca0286
   CSeq: 6002185 INVITE

   ------------------------------------------------------------------------
send 1218 bytes to udp/[192.168.28.31]:5060 at 05:12:37.202147:
   ------------------------------------------------------------------------
   INVITE sip:linphone@192.168.28.31;transport=udp SIP/2.0
   Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 192.168.2.180;rport;branch=z9hG4bKmZK62Ze622SZj
   Max-Forwards: 70
   From: "Outbound Call" <sip:50032.168.2.180@192.168.2.180>;tag=UNy45DKB778BS
   To: <sip:linphone@192.168.28.31;transport=udp>
   Call-ID: edb6b4b1-0eaf-1238-7aa7-080027ca0286
   CSeq: 6002185 INVITE
   Contact: <sip:mod_sofia@192.168.2.180:5060>
   User-Agent: FreeSWITCH-mod_sofia/1.6.10-17-726448d~64bit
   Allow: INVITE, ACK, BYE, CANCEL, OPTIONS, MESSAGE, INFO, UPDATE, REGISTER, REFER, NOTIFY, PUBLISH, SUBSCRIBE
   Supported: timer, path, replaces
   Allow-Events: talk, hold, conference, presence, as-feature-event, dialog, line-seize, call-info, sla, include-session-description, presence.winfo, message-summary, refer
   Content-Type: application/sdp
   Content-Disposition: session
   Content-Length: 224
   X-FS-Support: update_display,send_info
   Remote-Party-ID: "Outbound Call" <sip:5003%192.168.2.180@192.168.2.180>;party=calling;screen=yes;privacy=off

   v=0
   o=FreeSWITCH 1561093772 1561093773 IN IP4 192.168.2.180
   s=FreeSWITCH
   c=IN IP4 192.168.2.180
   t=0 0
   m=audio 18182 RTP/AVP 9 101
   a=rtpmap:9 G722/8000
   a=rtpmap:101 telephone-event/8000
   a=fmtp:101 0-16
   a=ptime:20
   ------------------------------------------------------------------------
recv 221 bytes from udp/[192.168.28.31]:5060 at 05:12:37.231809:
   ------------------------------------------------------------------------
   SIP/2.0 400 Bad request
   Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 192.168.2.180;rport;branch=z9hG4bKmZK62Ze622SZj
   To: <sip:linphone@192.168.28.31;transport=udp>;tag=oUWqD
   Call-ID: edb6b4b1-0eaf-1238-7aa7-080027ca0286
   CSeq: 6002185 INVITE

   ------------------------------------------------------------------------
send 1218 bytes to udp/[192.168.28.31]:5060 at 05:12:41.203772:
   ------------------------------------------------------------------------
   INVITE sip:linphone@192.168.28.31;transport=udp SIP/2.0
   Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 192.168.2.180;rport;branch=z9hG4bKmZK62Ze622SZj
   Max-Forwards: 70
   From: "Outbound Call" <sip:50032.168.2.180@192.168.2.180>;tag=UNy45DKB778BS
   To: <sip:linphone@192.168.28.31;transport=udp>
   Call-ID: edb6b4b1-0eaf-1238-7aa7-080027ca0286
   CSeq: 6002185 INVITE
   Contact: <sip:mod_sofia@192.168.2.180:5060>
   User-Agent: FreeSWITCH-mod_sofia/1.6.10-17-726448d~64bit
   Allow: INVITE, ACK, BYE, CANCEL, OPTIONS, MESSAGE, INFO, UPDATE, REGISTER, REFER, NOTIFY, PUBLISH, SUBSCRIBE
   Supported: timer, path, replaces
   Allow-Events: talk, hold, conference, presence, as-feature-event, dialog, line-seize, call-info, sla, include-session-description, presence.winfo, message-summary, refer
   Content-Type: application/sdp
   Content-Disposition: session
   Content-Length: 224
   X-FS-Support: update_display,send_info
   Remote-Party-ID: "Outbound Call" <sip:5003%192.168.2.180@192.168.2.180>;party=calling;screen=yes;privacy=off

   v=0
   o=FreeSWITCH 1561093772 1561093773 IN IP4 192.168.2.180
   s=FreeSWITCH
   c=IN IP4 192.168.2.180
   t=0 0
   m=audio 18182 RTP/AVP 9 101
   a=rtpmap:9 G722/8000
   a=rtpmap:101 telephone-event/8000
   a=fmtp:101 0-16
   a=ptime:20
   ------------------------------------------------------------------------
recv 221 bytes from udp/[192.168.28.31]:5060 at 05:12:41.234270:
   ------------------------------------------------------------------------
   SIP/2.0 400 Bad request
   Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 192.168.2.180;rport;branch=z9hG4bKmZK62Ze622SZj
   To: <sip:linphone@192.168.28.31;transport=udp>;tag=oUWqD
   Call-ID: edb6b4b1-0eaf-1238-7aa7-080027ca0286
   CSeq: 6002185 INVITE

   ------------------------------------------------------------------------
send 1218 bytes to udp/[192.168.28.31]:5060 at 05:12:49.205014:
   ------------------------------------------------------------------------
   INVITE sip:linphone@192.168.28.31;transport=udp SIP/2.0
   Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 192.168.2.180;rport;branch=z9hG4bKmZK62Ze622SZj
   Max-Forwards: 70
   From: "Outbound Call" <sip:50032.168.2.180@192.168.2.180>;tag=UNy45DKB778BS
   To: <sip:linphone@192.168.28.31;transport=udp>
   Call-ID: edb6b4b1-0eaf-1238-7aa7-080027ca0286
   CSeq: 6002185 INVITE
   Contact: <sip:mod_sofia@192.168.2.180:5060>
   User-Agent: FreeSWITCH-mod_sofia/1.6.10-17-726448d~64bit
   Allow: INVITE, ACK, BYE, CANCEL, OPTIONS, MESSAGE, INFO, UPDATE, REGISTER, REFER, NOTIFY, PUBLISH, SUBSCRIBE
   Supported: timer, path, replaces
   Allow-Events: talk, hold, conference, presence, as-feature-event, dialog, line-seize, call-info, sla, include-session-description, presence.winfo, message-summary, refer
   Content-Type: application/sdp
   Content-Disposition: session
   Content-Length: 224
   X-FS-Support: update_display,send_info
   Remote-Party-ID: "Outbound Call" <sip:5003%192.168.2.180@192.168.2.180>;party=calling;screen=yes;privacy=off

   v=0
   o=FreeSWITCH 1561093772 1561093773 IN IP4 192.168.2.180
   s=FreeSWITCH
   c=IN IP4 192.168.2.180
   t=0 0
   m=audio 18182 RTP/AVP 9 101
   a=rtpmap:9 G722/8000
   a=rtpmap:101 telephone-event/8000
   a=fmtp:101 0-16
   a=ptime:20
   ------------------------------------------------------------------------
recv 221 bytes from udp/[192.168.28.31]:5060 at 05:12:49.234961:
   ------------------------------------------------------------------------
   SIP/2.0 400 Bad request
   Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 192.168.2.180;rport;branch=z9hG4bKmZK62Ze622SZj
   To: <sip:linphone@192.168.28.31;transport=udp>;tag=oUWqD
   Call-ID: edb6b4b1-0eaf-1238-7aa7-080027ca0286
   CSeq: 6002185 INVITE

   ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be a bug in the VM-Image from freeswitch.com
Installing freeswitch 1.6 on Centos 7 or 1.6/1.8 Debian 9 manually both didn't produce that problem.